# Find Row of Partial String

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
Dim Name As Long
            With Application.WorksheetFunction
                 Name= .Match("Test:", Range("A1:A1000"), -1)
             End With
```

The full that I am searching for is "Test: Hello", but the word Hello does not always follow test so I don't want to use a full match. I saw the `Instr` function but I want to know the row of this partial match.

Comment: try `"Test:*"` with the wildcard.

Comment: I think though the `-1` needs to be `0` for it to find the correct row.

Comment: I didn't know you could use `With` with non-Ranges. Neat to know. You could alternatively use `Find()`: `Range("A:A").Find(What:=”Test:”,LookAt:=xlPart).Row`, but @ScottCraner has your answer with the wildcard.

Comment: @ScottCraner write that bad boy up and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the wildcard `*` in the formula to capture anything after `Test:`.

And we want to return the exact so the third criterion should be `0`:

```
Dim Name As Long
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Name= .Match("Test:*", Range("A1:A1000"), 0)
End With
```

Though this method vba will error out if no match is found.

We can remove the WorksheetFunction part and vba will pass the error so we can test for it:

```
Dim Name As Long
With Application
    If IsError(.Match("Test:*", Range("A1:A1000"), 0)) then
        msgbox "No match found"
    Else
        Name= .Match("Test:*", Range("A1:A1000"), 0)
    End if
End With
```

Comment: @AdamWarner  See edit for one more piece of information.

Comment: Any idea whether `.Match` is better to use over `Find().row`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I had this debate a while back and someone provided a link to a page where someone else had done the test and Match was quicker than Find.  Here is the [LINK](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)